# how to serve golang response with appropriate newline

Tags: http, go, encoding

writing simple golang web handler.
When a request comes in, just returns if as it is.

But there are some problems.
Here is my code.

```golang
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var b []byte
    var err error
    if b, err = ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // r.Body is just string 
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Println(string(b)) // check r.Body string here --- (1)
    // And send back as it is
    if err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(string(b)); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

```golang
func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    testStr := []rune{}
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 1; j++ {
            testStr = append(testStr, 'a'+rune(i))
        }
        testStr = append(testStr, '\n')
    }
    // testStr is string with '\n'
    // a
    // b
    // c
    reader := strings.NewReader(string(testStr))
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/handler", reader)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    Handler(w, req)
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(w.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(bodyBytes)) // check w.Body string here --- (2)
}
```

When test, the result is

```
(1) result
a
b
c

(2) result
"a\nb\nc\n"
```

How to send back as it is???

1. without double quotation
2. with newline (not string "\n")

Comment: Why are you using `json.Encoder` for a `text/plain` response? Why don't you just use `w.Write(b)`?

Comment: @mkopriva No reason can you tell me another way?